# Python pandas map multilevel column heading df to another df

Tags: python, pandas

what I am trying to do is use the map function to tie back a pivot table to another dataframe. A1:A4 are columns that denote a different location. So the value in the pivot table represents the # of instances at A1 or A3, etc.

I have one dataframe and one pivot table. The dataframe (df1) looks like this:

```
    SubscriberKey Inst    A1   A2   A3   A4
        'abc'      2      0    0     0    0
        'bcd'      4      0    0     0    0
        'cde'      1      0    0     0    0
        'def'      0      0    0     0    0
        'efg'      0      0    0     0    0
```

My pivot table (pt1) looks like this. It also has a multilevel column heading due to this being a pivot table. To clarify what I mean by multilevel column heading is that a single column heading outputs ('Instance', 'A1'). Anyways below is a snapshot of my pivot table (pt1):

```
     Subscriber Key Instance Instance Instance Instance
       Linkname       A1       A2       A3       A4
        'abc'          2         0       2        0
        'bcd'          4         1       1        2
        'cde'          1         1       0        0
```

I would like to somehow populate my df's A1:A4 columns based on what is in the pivot. The df has more subscriber keys than the pivot table contains and so the row counts are not the same.

The output would look like:

```
    SubscriberKey  Inst   A1  A2   A3  A4
        'abc'       2     0    0    2   0
        'bcd'       4     0    1    1   2
        'cde'       1     1    0    0   0
        'def'       0     0    0    0   0
        'efg'       0     0    0    0   0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks! I have already tried df1.update(pt1[column]) and it returns 'Type Error: expected tuple, got str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update should work. Try this:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('SubscriberKey')
df1


Output:             
             Inst   A1  A2  A3  A4
SubscriberKey                   
'abc'          1    0   0   0   0
'bcd'          2    0   0   0   0
'cde'          1    0   0   0   0
'def'          3    0   0   0   0
'efg'          0    0   0   0   0

df2 = df2[1:]
df2.columns = ["SubscriberKey","A1","A2","A3","A4"]
df2 = df2.set_index('SubscriberKey')



Output:
              A1    A2  A3  A4
SubscriberKey               
'abc'          1    0   2   0
'bcd'          0    1   1   2
'cde'          1    1   0   0
```

Then doing:

```
df1.update(df2)
df1
```

which gives:

```
              Inst  A1  A2  A3  A4
SubscriberKey                   
'abc'           1   1   0   2   0
'bcd'           2   0   1   1   2
'cde'           1   1   1   0   0
'def'           3   0   0   0   0
'efg'           0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hi updated my second dataframe to properly show how the columns are displaying-- when i use df2 = df2[1:], it actually cuts my first row and not the column heading

Answer (score 1):

```
df[['SubscriberKey','Inst']].join(pt1.set_index('Linkname'), on='SubscriberKey')
```

This works as well after you deal with the multi-level index. There are a number of ways to deal with that. I typically just use .reset_index()